# HTML email wont send correctly

Tags: php, html, email

Every time I try to send an email from my PHP file testsend.php it comes in as a plain text email and not a HTML email...

Here is my code.

```html
<?php
$to = "email@gmail.com";
$sub = "Rediku Verify";
$from = 'noreply@rediku.com';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$from."\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();

$message = '<html>';
$message .= '<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head>';
$message .= '<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">';
$message .= '<table width="100%" bgcolor="#ff5454" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0"><tr valign="top" align="center"><td>';
$message .= '<table width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ff6565">';
$message .= '<tr><td><img src="http://www.rediku.com/image/veriEm4.png" alt="Welcome To Rediku! Just verify your Account..." /></td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td style="padding:1em; font-family:Arial, Helvetica;"><h2 style="color:white; font-weight:200; letter-spacing:1px; font-size:1.15em; text-align:center;">Please click "Verify" below to continue to username selection...</h2></td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td style="padding:1em; font-family:Arial, Helvetica;"><a href="http://www.rediku.com/validate/vali.php">VALIDATE</a></td></tr>';
$message .= '</table></td></tr></table>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

if(mail($to, $sub, $message, $headers)){

    echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully.';

} else{

    echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';

}

?>
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong... Also, while your at it. How can I send Forms in my emails with out being classified as a spammer by email clients?

It's so annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers = 'From: '.$from."\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();
```

you overwrite $headers. You forgot the dot to add the from-line to $headers instead of replacing its content.

It needs to look like this:

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();
```

---

In order to display a name in the from instead of the email, write the from like that:

```
$from = 'Rediku <noreply@rediku.com>';
```

i.e. put the email-address into angle brackets and add the text to display in front of that.

Comment: Ah! ok cant believe I missed that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It says I cant do it for another 3 mins... I don't know why... I do have one more question...  Do you know how to make I so that the from address in the email bar say Rediku and not noreply@rediku.com

Comment: change your from to `$from = 'Rediku <noreply@rediku.com>'`